# gspreadによるスプシへの書き込み中のエラー

Tags: google-apps-script

gspreadライブラリを用いてスプレッドシートに書き込みをしている最中、以下のようなエラーが発生しました。

```
gspread.exceptions.APIError: {
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
```

前後で動作の変化はなく、同じような処理を繰り返している最中の1つでこのようなエラーが生じました。
このようなエラーは何故生じるのでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

例外のmessageに書かれている説明

> "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project."

[直訳] 要求に無効な資格証明情報(authentication credentials)が含まれていました。OAuth 2のアクセストークン(access token)、ログインクッキー、もしくは有効な資格証明情報を使ってください。
詳しくはhttps://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-projectを見てください。

を参考に、credentialの内容を確認して下さい。

OAuth 2のcredentialの有効期限は1時間(3600秒)なので、長時間操作していると期限切れになったりします。